# Could not create the view: com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.views.LayoutView

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to use android studio to pick the layout from my device. But when I try to open the Android Device Monitor, I got an error, it is said "Could not create the view: com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.views.LayoutView". Like this.[Android Device Monitor with error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xjxzs.png)
And also, I open the Layout inspector, only can see my phone process, cannot see any other activity or process.

Anyone can help me?

I have reinstall the android studio, and my phone is in Debugging model.
Android studio 2.3 on windows 10.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @sasha_trn, I download the sdk tools, and then replace the sdk under the Android studio with it. Seems that, it can work for me. You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio Tools>Android>SDK Manager>SDKTools
select "Android SDK Platform-Tools" and "Android SDK Tools" and update both.

You can also try to "run adb kill-server" and "adb start-server" in the Android Studio terminal view.